# Unable to reference System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;

Tags: asp.net, pie-chart

I need to create a Pie Chart. I am getting the error as `The type name 'Charting' does not exist in the type 'System.Web.UI.DataVisualization'`.

I am not able to find System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting in the references.

Can someone help me please.

Comment: The dll to refer is  System.Web.DataVisualization.dll. Have you referred that in your project?

Comment: Yes I have referred that. Basically I am trying to use DataPoint property for which I need to add System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting. But the code is not accepting this reference.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Add References in your project and in the .NET Components tab add the `System.Web.DataVisualization` dll. This should solve your problem.

Comment: How are you using Charting? I ask because Charting is not a type name, it is a namespace. Are you trying to create a chart like so:
System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart myChart = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting()

Comment: Yippee... My problem is solved. There was already a DataVisualization.cs file due to which it was unable to reference to System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting as it created a conflict. Looks like I accidentally added this file. Thank you Mark and Piyush for your inputs.